# repair ubuntu folders Icon

Tags: icons, directory, desktop-environments

My Ubuntu folder icons are damaged. How can I repair it?

[image]

Comment: Did you mess with the icon pack or theme?

Comment: when i srart my ubuntu the font on desktop is too big. then I install unity-tweak-tool and use the "Restore defaults" in the Fonts tab:<sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool>. after changing the font. the folder icons damaged

Comment: It seems that theme is missing. Go to System Settings - Appearance. The theme setting must be blank. Choose a theme.